# sort ArrayList based on criteria using SQL query or Java

Tags: java, sql, angularjs

> I have one employee table in Database have columns emp_id , superior_id, name etc.
>
> I am trying to generate tree using js library.
>
> every employee has superior_id except manager. so the js input I want should be like

`manager names --
   lead name--
      employee name
      employee name
      employee name
   lead name

      employee name
   lead name
      employee name`

but the result I am getting is like

`manager name
   lead name
   lead name

   lead name
      employee name
      employee name
      employee name
      employee name
      employee name`

> SQL query I have written is

```
SELECT 
  t1.emp_id, 
  t1.emp_name, 
  t1.tcs_mail, 
  t1.boeing_mail, 
  t1.contact_no, 
  t2.emp_id as superior_id
FROM employee_master AS t1
LEFT JOIN employee_master AS t2 ON t2.emp_id = t1.superior_id
LEFT JOIN employee_master AS t3 ON t3.emp_id = t2.superior_id
ORDER BY t3.emp_id,t2.emp_name LIMIT 10
```

Please help me with with this.

Comment: Is this really the query? ...FROM employee_master AS t1" + "... what is this? Does does even work?

Comment: sorry i just took the my java code where superior_id will be replaced by real id

Comment: is this mysql or something else?

Comment: yes query is in mysql

Comment: if somebody help with the logic will be helpful

Comment: I would suggest not sorting in SQL, but have Java code build the tree/hierarchy and sort each level of the tree.

Comment: SQL is not a powerful language to do sorting.As Andreas said it would be good practise to sort in JAVA.

Comment: could you please help me with the logic or code. I am getting sql output in ArrayList

Comment: @Andreas, no, there is no problem in sorting in SQL - in fact, he should do that. The problem is in his query - it doesn't do what he needs.

Comment: Using GroupBy may solve the issue. But better go for Java programming for sorting.

Comment: @KayV, "going for Java sorting" implies he has to load **whole table** into the memory, and then sorting over that. I'd say that is a **horrible** advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not right - if you are really want to build a tree, you need query that will provide you with one, which means hierarchical SQL query.

Unfortunately, I wasn't really able to find simple way to construct a hierarchical query in MySQL dialect. If you only know that there will always be no more than three nesting levels of your tree, you may be able to emulate hierarchy using several counters:

```
with first_level(emp_id, emp_name, rnum, rnum2, rnum3) as (
  -- first we retrieve all employees that do not have any superiors
  -- there first counter is ordering of those employees, other counters are zero (see below)
    select emp_id, emp_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by emp_name) as rnum, 0 as rnum2, 0 as rnum3
    from employee_master
    where superior_id is null
  ),
  second_level(emp_id, emp_name, rnum, rnum2, rnum3) as (
  -- then we need subordinates of top superiors. There first counter should represent ordering of the superior
  -- second counter should represent ordering of the subordinate and last counter is zero
    select s.emp_id, s.emp_name, f.rnum, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by f.rnum, s.name) as rnum2, 0 as rnum3
    from employee_master s
    inner join first_level f on f.emp_id = s.superior_id
  ),
  third_level(emp_id, emp_name, rnum, rnum2, rnum3) as (
  -- our last query level. It will have first two counters joined from higher levels and last counter will be the own level ordering
    select s.emp_id, s.emp_name, f.rnum, f.rnum2, row_number() over (order by f.rnum, f.rnum2, s.name) as rnum3
    from employee_master s
    inner join second_level f on f.emp_id = s.superior_id
  )

-- lastly, we combine all of the above into a single query:
select
  emp_id,
  emp_name,
  rnum, rnum2, rnum3
from first_level
union all
select
  emp_id,
  emp_name,
  rnum, rnum2, rnum3
from second_level
union all
select
  emp_id,
  emp_name,
  rnum, rnum2, rnum3
from third_level
order by rnum, rnum2, rnum3
```

Note that since I've used *WITH* clauses, above query is valid only on MySQL 8.0 and above.

You can also see here for more general solution: [ExplainExtended:Hierarchical Queries in MySQL](https://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/)

**Edit:**
Here is also some material on how to construct a hierarchical self-joining query in MySQL 8.0 and above: [MySQL Server Team:Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/).
This might help you solve the problem of possibly unbounded max tree heights, but looks like it might require you to jump some hoops to achieve proper ordering (for example, obtaining current tree nest level, concating it into a varchar and ordering over that).